# Making a 2d game in Python - which library should be used?

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine, pyglet

I'm looking to make a 2d side scrolling game in Python, however I'm not sure what library to use. I know of PyGame (Hasn't been updated in 3 years), Pyglet, and PyOpenGL. My problem is I can't find any actually shipped games that were made with Python, let alone these libraries - so I don't know how well they perform in real world situations, or even if any of them are suitable for use in an **actual** game and not a competition.

Can anyone please shed some light on these libraries? Is PyGame still used effectively? Is Pyglet worth while? Have either of them been used to make a game? Are there any other libraries I'm forgetting?

Honestly I'm not even sure I want to use Python, it seems too slow, unproven (For games written solely in Python), etc.... I have not found any game that was made primarily in Python, for sure, that has been sold. If I don't end up going with Python, what would a second/better choice be? Java? LUA?

Comment: Games in pure Python seem indeed rare, but games written *mostly* in Python do happen. Consider Civilization 4 (does almost all GUI work and a good share of logic in Python) and Eve Online (reportedly almost exclusively Stackless Python on the server side).

Comment: (Also see http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames -- section "Specific Games".)

Comment: Pygame is totally fine for (small sized, pc based) game development, but of course you won't find any AAA-titles written in pygame (professional game development is dominated by C++, at least for PC). Have also a look into [Cocos2D](http://cocos2d.org/), which greatly enhances pyglet. Just google a little bit, you'll find tons of games written in pygame, and also some written in pyglet, but don't expect to find AAA titles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pygame is just a wrapper for SDL, so technically a lot of games have been made using it, most of the work is done C-side anyways. It's a little slow, though if you are doing a 2D game, it should be sufficient. [Frets-on-Fire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/) was written in pure python with PyGame, and [FoFiX](http://code.google.com/p/fofix/) was written in python with C extensions, and those games are both pretty great, altough on slower computers FoFiX can have trouble running 4 player.

Pyglet is also pretty nice, though I've only used it for emulator development, drawing single layers, so I don't know how well it actually works for game development. I've found that it's much easier to use direct OpenGL with Pyglet than it is with SDL/PyGame, so if you are doing a 3D game, it's probably better than using SDL. Also, since it's written in python, it's very easy to extend classes to change how a function is handled. For instance, I was trying to load data into an openGL texture through the pyglet Texture class, but the class couldn't load the data in a format I wanted, so I extended that class and changed the function that got the texture type (comes from a string) to include the texture I wanted, quick and painless.

One library I don't see mentioned enough is [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/). The 2.0 API (currently in beta) is pretty stellar and simple to use, and, if I remember correctly, runs a little faster than SDL. It is also more "object oriented" than SDL, which is really nice if you are working in an OO language like Python. It has some nice Python bindings written by Bastien Leonard in Cython that are pretty easy to use (or you can use the old C bindings if you don't want to use the most up to date version). I used this a while back and it was quite an enjoyable experience.

The reason why there aren't a lot of shipped games using Python is pretty simple: You can't close Python source. Even if you "compile" python into an executable using Py2Exe or something, it really just packs up the interpreter and python source into an exe file, and the source can be got just by opening up the exe in a hex editor.

While I'm a supporter of the "write it in Python, write time critical parts in C", if you feel python is going to be too slow, I would probably suggest C or, preferably, C++ as the way to go, simply because you don't get that much of a usability advantage for writing in Java, and the C languages can be quite a bit faster running than Java, and Lua will just take away some of the usability of Python without giving you any noticeable performance enhancement. SFML and SDL can both be used straight from C(++).

Advice if you do decide to use python: Use it as it is supposed to be used, as a scripting language. Do not try to bit twiddle or load images in pure python, either use the interfaces available in the library you choose (they all have very good interfaces for those kinds of things) or write an extension module to do that for you. Use python for logic control and fetching data from your libraries. If you follow that simple rule, you really shouldn't run into any performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the things that are *really* going to kill you aren't generally related to graphics at all. Sure, it's a challenge to get all your frame rendering done in less than 16 ms without techniques like dirty-rectangle updating, but that's not going to be the *big* thing you'll lose sleep over. The biggest performance considerations are going to come from much more elementary things - collision detection, spatial searching, and pathfinding are three of the big ones - that can easily send your logic frame rate into the floor if done inefficiently over even a few hundred objects. For problems like these, pure Python may not be the best choice, but it's not hard to offload these to C/C++ while retaining Python for higher-level logic. This is essentially what games like Civilization 4 and EVE Online (client and server!) do - offload performance-critical code to C++ while retaining the flexibility and simplicity of Python for 'everyday' tasks.

pygame is actively developed (they haven't had a stable release in a while, but the Mercurial repository is quite lively) and fairly popular. It also uses the well-regarded (C-based!) SDL library under the hood. pyglet is also actively developed and uses OpenGL for all of its rendering, making moving to 3D development easier if you're planning to go in that direction (since you'll already have most of the basics).

If you decide to go the not-Python route, you can use SDL directly with C/C++, along with addon libraries like SDL_gfx (for primitives), SDL_ttf (for text), and SDL_net (for basic networking). Another excellent and widely used alternative for C/C++ is [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/). I've used both, and I will claim that it's largely a matter of taste which one you go with.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame should suffice for what you want to do. Pygame is stable and if you look around the websites you will find games which have been coded in pygame. What type of game are you looking to implement?